# C++ how can I move a code from the main

Tags: c++

I have little knowlage in C++
so I have this code

```
bool is_successful = true;
ex_file_licensing exFileLicence;
std::string flexLMfilePath;
flexLMfilePath.append("C:/Desktop/QA-program/testsuite/tmp/");
std::string Message = exFileLicence.checkLicense(DI_MF,flexfilePath,is_successful);
```

and I was asked to move it outside the main and then call it in the main 
and now I have no idea what to do 
Could you please tell me what are the steps that I should follow 
please be as specific as possible, I'm really bad at this thing

Thanks

Comment: You need to write a function.  But really, if you have literally no experience with C++, you should get a [decent introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: For more information on how to create functions, please see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/35690/

Answer (score 2):

You must create a function and call that function inside main:

```
void foo(); //this is called a function prototype

main()
{
...
foo() //your function in place of that code
}

void foo()
{
...//the code originally in main.  This is called your function definition
}
```

this is how creating functions works and is basically how any code in c++ is written.  Sometimes the functions appear in files outside the main file but its basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check out C++ Functions. I'm assuming you have something as follows.

```
int main(){
    //***your stuff
return
```

You need the following.

```
void function(){
    //**your stuff
return;
}

int main(){

      function();

return;
}
```

When the program starts it will automatically go to main and when it reaches the call:
    function();

It will pass control to the code wrapped within

```
void function(){

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think you just need to put the code in a function, like this:

```
void CodeFunction()
{
    bool is_successful = true; 
    ex_file_licensing exFileLicence; 
    std::string flexLMfilePath; 
    flexLMfilePath.append("C:/Desktop/QA-program/testsuite/tmp/"); 
    std::string Message = exFileLicence.checkLicense(DI_MF,flexfilePath,is_successful); 
}
```

and you can then call it from `main` by using `CodeFunction()`.

Remember to put this above the `main` function, or if it's below declare it above `main` using

`void CodeFunction();`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function, move the code to the function and then call the function from main - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/